# Jest only - addEventListener ~ click assertion

Tags: jasmine, tdd, jestjs, jsdom

I want to mock a normal dom click as [indicated](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-jquery#docsNav) in the Jest docs:

```
test('displays a user after a click', () => {

  document.body.innerHTML =
    '<div>' +
    '  <span id="username" />' +
    '  <button id="button" />' +
    '</div>';

  // Use jquery to emulate a click on our button
  $('#button').click();

  expect($('#username').text()).toEqual('Johnny Cash - Logged In');
});
```

My function is as follows:

```
function clickTrack() {
    const data = {};
    document.addEventListener('click', function clicked(e) {
        if (e.target.matches('a')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            data['click.Classes'] = e.target.classList;
            data['click.ID'] = e.target.id;
            data['click.Destination'] = e.target.href;
            data['click.ElementText'] = e.target.innerText;
        }
    }, false);
    return data;
}
```

And the test:

```
describe('Click Tracking', () => {

    test('Clicking on an a tag will collect its information', () => {
        clickTrack();
        document.body.innerHTML = '<a class="j1 j2 j3" id="j" href="http://www.google.com/">Jest</a>';
        document.getElementById('j').click();
        expect(clickTrack()).toEqual({a:'b'});
    });

});
```

I expect the output to be vaguely:

```
   {
    click.Classes: ["j1 j2 j3"]
    click.Destination: "https://www.google.com/"
    click.ElementText: "Jest"
    click.ID: "j"
   }
```

But an empty object is returned instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clickTrack` hooks up a `click` event listener and returns a `data` object that will be updated whenever a click event happens, so you only have to call `clickTrack` once.

Right now you are calling it again *after* your click event so it is creating an *additional* `click` listener and returning a new, empty `data` object.

You'll also want to use `e.target.text` for the text and get the class names by calling `split(' ')` on `e.target.className`:

```js
function clickTrack() {
  const data = {};
  document.addEventListener('click', function clicked(e) {
    if (e.target.matches('a')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      data['click.Classes'] = e.target.className.split(' ');
      data['click.ID'] = e.target.id;
      data['click.Destination'] = e.target.href;
      data['click.ElementText'] = e.target.text;
    }
  }, false);
  return data;
}

describe('Click Tracking', () => {

  test('Clicking on an a tag will collect its information', () => {
    const data = clickTrack();
    document.body.innerHTML = '<a class="j1 j2 j3" id="j" href="http://www.google.com/">Jest</a>';
    document.getElementById('j').click();
    expect(data).toEqual({
      'click.Classes': ['j1', 'j2', 'j3'],
      'click.Destination': 'http://www.google.com/',
      'click.ElementText': 'Jest',
      'click.ID': 'j'
    });  // Success!
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you, that was very nicely explained. I understand now that it makes sense for the listener to be there before the 'click' in the test.